# VBA: Loop Running - Not Throwing Error. Not Performing

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you're all well. I am in the process of working through an excel sheet that has 132 rows of data. In Column H of that data I have cells of comma separated values, that contain a list of countries. The problem with the list of countries is that I keep receiving it in a non-standardized format. I am attempting to standardize it now. With some help, I have written a VBA macro that is supposed to loop through column H, with the standardized values, and their non-standardized values in a separate sheet, Sheets(4). In Column A of Sheets4, I have the non-standardized value, in column B of Sheets(4) I have the standardized values, which I desire to be brought over and then replaced for the various non-standardized values in column A.

When I run the macro however, it appears as if it is not running at all. It takes about 5 minutes to run, and when it's done, none of the changes have occurred. Here are some of the things I have tried to make sure that none of the obvious things are at work with the macro:

1. I have tried to deliberately insert the exact error text I have in Column A of Sheets(4) of Sheets4, so that it will automatically pick up on the text, as they are the exact image and mirror of eachother.
2. I have gone into the "Views", "Local Window" and followed the variable step by step after running through the code step by step to make sure that I am actually following the proper procedure and that in each case it is *picking up* and detecting the the different errors in each case.

[image]

3. tried turning on and off the computer.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I should do in order to get this Macro running?

```
Sub Translate_Country_Name()
    'Variable Names
    Dim Ary As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets(4)
        Ary = .Range("A2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With Sheets(1).Range("H:H")
        For i = 1 To UBound(Ary)
            .Replace Chr(160), " ", xlPart, , , , False, False
            .Replace Ary(i, 1), Ary(i, 2), xlPart, , True, , False, False
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using sheet indexes which may not be what you think, e.g. `Sheet4` is not necessarily the same as `Sheets(4)`.

Comment: But check the link of the photo I added "Ary" - it is clearly picking it up.

Comment: Sorry I'd rather not click on an unknown link, please can you upload pic here?

Comment: I think that did it. Looks like someone else did it. Not sure if my edit did it, or someone else.

Comment: You only need to run `.Replace Chr(160)` once ,so move it out of the loop.  Probably also ditch those last `False, False` in the `Replace` call

Comment: But is it replacing on the right sheet?

Comment: I just replaced "Sheets(1)" to the name of the sheet. Let us see what it does.

Comment: Huh... look at that. Son of a gun. You were right.

Comment: I did not want to hear it. but you were right.

Comment: It's got to happen every now and then by the law of averages.

Comment: You know whats funny about that? Sheets(4) is correct but Sheets(1) is not. I'm a green horn to VBA so I'll take the hit... but that seems strange. I know how to check the indexes of sheets and I specifically looked.